# jqueryui css 'right' not applied in ie

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I am trying to move an adjacent element after a text area has been re-sized, using the stop event on jqueryUIs resizable:

```
$("textarea").resizable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var x = ui.originalElement.closest("li").find(".targettomove");
        if (x != null) {
             var y = ui.originalElement.width() + 70;
             $(x).css({ right: -y + "px" });   
        }
    }
});
```

The code works in Firefox 22 but not IE 10. The problem seems that the css setting of the right attribute is not being applied. Inspection of the attribute shows it unchanged.

Comment: Since you said it's unchanged - are you sure that line is even getting hit, if you step through with a debugger?

Comment: And is the element `absolute` or `relative` position, not `static`?

Comment: `targettomove` is `absolute`, and i have stepped through the code in the debugger so i know its being hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I changed `ui.originalElement.width()` to `ui.element.width()`.

Perhaps I was accessing the wrong property all along but it doesn't seem to update as it does in Firefox compared to Internet Explorer.